# Best S.E.O. practice for backlinking etc

Tags: seo, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I'm currently working on a website that I am really looking to optimise in terms of search engines, i've been submitting between 5-20 directory submissions daily, i've validated and optimised my code and i've joined a lot of forums etc to speak of the website in question, however, I don't seem to be making much of an impact in terms of Google.

I know that S.E.O. takes a while to start making an impact, and that Google prefers sites that a regularly updated and aged, but are there any more practices that can really help with organic results in Search engines. I have looked on Google itself, and a few other SE's but nobody is willing to talk about extensive S.E.O. practices as they normally don't want people knowing their formula's for S.E.O., also does anyone know of a decent piece of software that really looks into the in's and out's of your page and provides feedback, I usually use http://www.woorank.com, but only using one program doesn't show if it's exactly correct in what it's saying.

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: There are probably two reasons why people are unwilling to talk. 1. It's something you can make money out of, so you don't want to give much away for free. 2. Actually nobody knows for sure what works, apart from the people who work for the search engines, so no-one can give you guarantees.

Comment: Very true, I just wondered if there were any obvious areas really that I could do more with, for example I have been looking more into Social Networking seo, but is there anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN'T boost your ranking as simple as that (using softwares or any of these).

The only way to SEO your website is to actively manage the content as best as you can (adding sentences with new keywords that is characterizing the subject of the pages for example) and talk about it on appropriate forums with the hope to expand the net between your site and others.

Netlinking would be the accurate way to up your website in the search results, no secret.

Comment: What a ridiculous answer, you've clearly skimmed through this post and assumed wrongly, not once does it mention at all that I would like to use a software to boost my SEO, and it already speaks about backlinking and how i'm putting it into practice, next time read the question.

Comment: please, don't be rude I was just trying to help...

Comment: I wasn't being rude, and it certainly didn't seem you where trying to help at all.